# scrollingtabs and viewpager

Tags: java, android, menu, tabs, android-tabs

I am using tabs and viewpager. the tabs are specials and friends, and I want adding new tabs (checkin). so the new tabs will be like this, checkin-specials-friends. The new tabs will have their own layout and class of course. The question is, how am I supposed to do that (adding new tabs)? In the code I mean.

[myhome.java](https://www.dropbox.com/s/94nujxc2pibi16o/Home.java)

[myhome.xml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/61y1saf7ewl6t78/home.xml)

Comment: its done. i can added it. its using inflater. can inflater be used with intent? i already try it, but it showing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use onCLickListener and added an intent in it.